# Comparing database value ignoring duplicate spaces

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a webpage that contains a field `Patient Name`. Once I enter the name, it fetches the data from `sql database` and displays the `age` and `relation` of the member entered in text-box.

Now the issue is that it returns zero rows if there is a mistake in spacing while entering data in database.

**For example**

If the database contains name `Suresh Patel`, i.e. two spaces between the name and surname due to the mistake of data entry operator and I entered in text-box `Suresh Patel`, i.e. single space between name and surname, it doesn't return the age and relation of `Suresh`, since the value in the database and text-box don't match due to extra spacing in value of database.

I need your help to find a way to exclude `ALL` the spaces in the text-box and database while comparing them.

Comment: ALL the spaces or duplicate spaces? It may be usefull to match "Foo___Bar" to "Foo_Bar", but if you remove all spaces you will match "FooB__ar" also

Comment: yes i meant the first one. that means it shouldn't matter how much space has been left between the first and last name

Comment: If you want to ignore ALL the spaces, this question has a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709929/query-that-ignore-the-spaces

Comment: OK, so remove duplicate spaces - understood.

Comment: other question: would it be acceptable to update the db table to remove the duped spaces? That way you would use cleaned up data instead of circumventing error while performing the search.

Comment: no.. that is not possible.. how can search the whole table and check whether each entered name has correct spacing or not?! i just want some code that can delete all spaces from the text entered in textbox and value fetched from database and then compare it

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but Keshava edit suggested me that I may have misunderstood you. Do you need that "Suresh Patel" (one space) match to "SureshPatel" (NO SPACES) or only to consider duplicated spaces as a single space? I assumed the second, but it seems you are fine with the first, right?

Comment: yes.. the second option could be the best where there would be no mistakes while entering data in database. but since i want to fetch the data that has already been in database so far and there was no such way where in i could be sure that the operator wouldnt have made a mistake. so now the issue is that if i write "suresh patel", i.e, single space in textbox and search and if the record contains two spaces then the data isnot fetched from database. so i want a way to compare and search from databse excluding spaces from the data in database and the name entered in textbox. now do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you , while inserting members name you can use regular expression validator for exact match. Below regular expression will not allow space in the start and in the end and also will not allow two consecutive white spaces in the middle of the string. See also
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

```
regex = re.compile(
    """^          # Start of string
    (?![ ])       # Assert no space at the start
    (?!.*[ ]{2})  # Assert no two spaces in the middle
    (?!.*[ ]$)    # Assert no space at the end
    [A-Z. ]{8,20} # Match 8-20 ASCII letters, dots or spaces
    $             # End of string""", 
    re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: yes mr afnan. thank you for the code. but this is possible for the new entries.. if i now add this code, it will not allow any extra spaces during dataentry. but what about the data that has already been entered in the database? so i want a solution that compares two values irre4spective of the space given in both values

Comment: @user3036372 valid argument. Then I think you should follow the instructions of SPArchaeologist

Comment: @AfnanAhmad - the linked post in my comment above would remove all spaces, not only duped ones. So basically in the end "Foo Bar" would equal to "FooB ar"

Comment: FOO BAR is equal to FOOB AR does not matter since i just have to compare names from database which will contain only two words. but i dint get the code! how can i insert this code for my usage? since the data is fetched from database and then compared to the text in the textbox

Comment: @user3036372 Wait - do you mean that you fetch all data and then filter it code side?

Comment: i will explain you the whole process. i have to fetch data using policy no. once i get the data, i write down the patient name in textbox and it compares the data fetched from database to check if the name entered is the primary member, secondary member or child and according to that it fetches the value of age and relation from database and displays it. Now i just have to compare the name entered in textbox with each name in database (primary, secondary and child)..so it doesnt matter if i compare the values after deleting all spaces from both, name fetched from db and name entered in textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multiple spaces with a single space.

You can update database with following code:

```
string name = "ali  reza"; //get name from data base
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Don't get it... what if a duplicate space is present on the DB side? the above will only manage user input from the textbox, right? The question above implicates that there are dupe spaces in the data stored in the db. Are you suggesting to read all data and filter via a regex on the .net code side?