# SQL query to ignore space

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-ce

Is there anyway to ignore spaces in a SQL query *only from right and left* of a string so that I can find `' alex '` (**not** `' i am alex jolig '`) by searching for `'alex'`?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709929/query-that-ignore-the-spaces) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709954/2263683), but the solution removes all the spaces in the string.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
    WHERE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') = REPLACE("John Bob Jones", ' ', '')
```

By the way, I'm using `Sql Server Compact Edition`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RTRIM()` to remove spaces from the right and `LTRIM()` to remove spaces from the left hence left and right spaces removed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = LTRIM(RTRIM("John Bob Jones"))
```

Comment: Just the one I need :)

Comment: National Character VARYING vs National Char FixedLength VaryingFalse could be the reason you are having to do this.  FYI

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RTRIM()` to remove spaces from the right of string and `LTRIM()` to remove spaces from the left of string.

Hence left and right spaces removed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = LTRIM(RTRIM("bod alias baby"))
```