# SQL LIKE Statement with Spaces

Tags: sql

Spaces in my phone numbers are causing issues when I am trying to search.

`Select * from customers where number LIKE '%02722231%'`

This will return records that're LIKE '02722231', but this will not return any records that contain a space e.g. '027 22231'

Can this be done with regular expressions? I need to search 0272542155 and get all records the same including 027 2542155

Comment: Try to remove all space first.  Moreover, you should state which RDMS you are using, e.g. sqlserver, mysql, oracle...

Comment: You can use REPLACE to replace space('  ') with (''). see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709929/query-that-ignore-the-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from customers where REPLACE(number, ' ', '') LIKE '%02722231%'
```

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou. I did look at this. I was soo close: SELECT * FROM customers WHERE REPLACE(number," ", "") = '02722231';   I needed to use the LIKE function still.

Comment: No worries :) happy to help