# Postgresql query to search by first and last name, what indexes should I create?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I'm using this query to search by "first and last name" or by "last and first name":

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    "firstname",
    "lastname"
FROM
    "plyers"
WHERE
  lower( REPLACE ( CONCAT ( lastname, firstname ), ' ', '' ) ) LIKE '%joh%'
  OR
  lower( REPLACE ( CONCAT ( firstname, lastname ), ' ', '' ) ) LIKE '%joh%'
ORDER BY "id" DESC
```

### GIVEN THAT

1. I'm using Postgresql 13
2. User can search with "`John Belushi`" or "`Belushi John`" or "`lushi`" or "`lushi jo`"
3. The search text (`joh` in this case) is always `lowered()` and cleaned of every space: before, during and after each word. E.g. if I write " `lushi JO` " the final search text is: "`lushijo`"
4. This query is used A LOT to search for players in a list and for the automatic completion of some selects

### QUESTIONS

1. Do you think it's a good query?
2. Do you think there is a way I can avoid `CONCAT(lastname,firstname)` and `CONCAT(firstname,lastname)`?
3. What indexes should I create? I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709967/10088259 but I didn't quite understand how to use it.

Comment: @MarkByers I'm citing your answer, can you explain it better with an example?

Comment: In any database, indexes only help when a WHERE (or a JOIN condition, for that matter) works on expression compared directly with the value in the column. As soon as you compare with a derivation of the value in the column, any possibly existing index is just toast. And OR-ing several predicates together adds to the un-optimiseable complexity...

Comment: @marcothesane, thanks. What do you think about this query?

Comment: Do you want to allow people to (successfully) search with 'ushijo' or 'hnbel'.  If not, then concatenating them with no space between seem like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Your question number 2 seems to be directly answered by your given number 3.  Is that given not really a given?

Answer (score 3):

Use [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-generated-columns.html), and put indices on those.

```
ALTER TABLE test
    ADD COLUMN first_last text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (lower(REPLACE(first || last, ' ', ''))) STORED;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS players_first_last_idx ON test USING gin (first_last gin_trgm_ops);

ALTER TABLE test
    ADD COLUMN last_first text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (lower(REPLACE(last || first, ' ', ''))) STORED;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS players_first_last_idx ON test USING gin (last_first gin_trgm_ops);
```

Now the `WHERE` clause will be able to use the indices:

```
SELECT
    "id",
    "firstname",
    "lastname"
FROM
    "plyers"
WHERE
  first_last LIKE '%joh%'
  OR
  last_first LIKE '%joh%'
ORDER BY "id" DESC
```

Good explanation of creating indices for `LIKE` queries: https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer using an "Answer" instead of a "Comment" ...

If you want to allow for the versatility that you suggest -

1. A fast data access - taking advantage of any existing indexes, is only possible if you allow for a case-sensitive search argument for the start of the string. My biggest tables of this type were never in PostreSQL, but in 3 or 4 other brands. But all of them, when using an index, did better with `WHERE fname >='Johnny' AND fname < 'Johnz'` than with `WHERE NAME LIKE 'Johnny%'`. I actually once coded a front-end to do that change for me ...
2. It helps, if you can, to actually add a column `fullname VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT firstname||' '||lastname` to your table (length guessed as about double the length of `firstname` and `lastname`  - keep it as short as you can afford without truncating the strings.
3. Add non-unique one-column indexes for `firstname`, `lastname`, and your new `fullname`.
4. Finally, be frank and open to the end users, telling them that an "begins-with" predicate will always be considerably faster than a "contains" predicate - let alone a case insensitive predicate.

If your front-end is a normal SQL client, the end-user must code their queries to respect the points above.

If you build your own front-end application, allow in the search functionality for "is equal to, case sensitive", "begins with. case sensitive" and a comparison with `firstname`, `lastname`, and, if it makes sense, `fullname` - as the preferred search method, but then also for "contains", "begins-with" - "is ''equal'' to" and "contains", all case insensitive - but with a warning, in the dialogue or the docu, that these latter ones are much slower.