# TypeORM : Make search space insensitive

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

I am building a simple search functionality,
the records can be like

```
AB CD
A BCD
ABC D
ABD C
```

now, if I give "`BCD`" as the search text,
I should be able to get

```
AB CD
A BCD
ABC D
```

Below, is the current query

```
await connection.manager
.createQueryBuilder(RefTransaction, 'rt')
.where('rt.key LIKE :searchText',
      {searchText: '%' + <searchText> + '%' })
.getRawMany();
```

How should I modify this ?

Post Note : Just read about replace function in MySQL, how can I use that in typeorm for the purpose mentioned

Comment: Might not be the best-case scenario here, but you could split `searchText` per character and append `%` in-between. It would give you the results you want, but I don't think it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Good suggestion @Valamorde, but may attract extra results like ABECED

Comment: Would this solve your case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709954/4139312 (Fixed the link)

Comment: I have used that in MySQL, wanted to know how to apply it in typeORM.
found out with some git examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
await connection.manager
.createQueryBuilder(RefTransaction, 'rt')
.where('replace(rt.key, " ", "") LIKE :searchText',
      {searchText: '%' + <searchText>.replace(" ","") + '%' })
.getRawMany();
```